# MemoryStream to virtual file

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I have the following:

```
using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
   gc.CreatePackage(memoryStream);
}
```

MemoryStream spits out an excel fil.  From the memoryStream, how do I go about actually showing the file that is produced. Note that I do not want to actually save the file to disk but merely display it.

So far I have the following but doesn't seem to work:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    gc.CreatePackage(memoryStream);

    using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite("Test.xlsx"))
    {
        memoryStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
    }                
}
```

But not sure if I am on the right direction. I get an error saying:

> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File(byte[], string)' is a 'method', which
>   is not valid in the given context

I am not sure if I am going about this in the right direction.

Comment: You would have to prefix it with the namespace `System.IO.File`

Comment: How do you want to display it? You mention `MVC`, do you want to write it to the `Response`? Doing a `File.OpenWrite` will write the file to disk, which is sounds like isn't what you want.

Comment: @DaveZych - I do not want to write it on disk but merely show it from what is in Memory. The idea is that when I show it to them, they can then save it to disk if need be or merely discard it. So do I use a Response in order for this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the assumption that you are using ASP.NET MVC, you probably want the [File response helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493017%28v=vs.98%29.aspx):

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    gc.CreatePackage(memoryStream);
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return File(memoryStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
}
```

If you want to have the file source actually appear in the browser, you can also lie about the MIME type and use `text/plain` instead. The browser will most likely render this as plain text.

You can also add a third parameter to `File` in order to specify the filename the download should appear to the end-user to be.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error you post seems to indicate that you're trying to return a generated file from an MVC controller, I think this may be what you're looking for.

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        gc.CreatePackage(memoryStream);
        //Make sure the position of the stream is at 0
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        //Return the contents of the stream with the appropriate MIME type
        return File(memoryStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MemoryMappedFile to create a virtual file.

example code:

Write:

```
  using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("MappedFileName", size, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWriteExecute))
   {
       using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor())
       {
            accessor.Write(Write your data to mapped file);
       }
    }
```

Read:

```
  using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("MappedFileName"))
    {
        using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor())
        {
            accessor.Read......
        }
    }
```